# Cannot save PDF from web directly to SP2010 doc library

Tags: document-library, pdf, web

Very annoying scenario for my end users:

They browse the web, find a useful PDF with good info and want to share it on our intranet.
They open the PDF in the browser (IE8) and click on the Save a Copy icon.

A Windows dialogue pops up, and they can click on My Network Places to find a Document Library on our intranet where they would like to save this PDF (SP2010 environment).

Error: You cannot save in the folder specified. Choose another location.

This error forces them first to download a copy of the PDF, and then browse to the doc library, then upload.

Ideally, they could skip the first steps of saving to their local machine. And also be taken to the Edit Properties Form to enter meta data right away.
Because if they upload to a doc library with thousands of documents, they will not find that doc anymore. They are then discouraged.

Is there any way to make this process faster/better for my users?
Because it is a real day-to-day annoyance and a time consumer.

Specs of our environment and machines:
Windows XP Pro SP3
IE8
Adobe Reader X
Office 2007

SharePoint Server 2010 Standard

Answer (score 1):

Each Document Library in SharePoint 2010 actually has a property titled BrowserFileHandling that is set based on the BrowserFileHandling selection at the Web Application level. SharePoint 2010 utilizes an enhanced security feature in Internet Explorer 8 and above to block the opening of file types it considers vulnerable to scripting or other attacks, such as PDFs, HTML, etc. We can modify SharePoint's behavior by changing the Browser File Handling option in the Web Application General Settings of SharePoint 2010 web application. We have two options: Strict (being the default) and Permissive.

More Information is available [here](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1187)